# UTC millisecond timestamps in SQLite R-Tree

Tags: sqlite, encoding, floating-point, precision, r-tree

I have two-dimensional data where one of the dimensions is a UTC timestamp with millisecond precision, and the other is an unbounded float. I want to use `rtree` virtual table module to index this data:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE samples USING rtree(
    id,
    min_time, max_time,
    min_value, max_value
)
```

However, since `rtree` is using 32-bit floats internally, at the magnitude of today's timestamp values the difference between consecutive representible values is more than two minutes. This results in significant slowdowns due to lots (thousands in the worst case) of spurious objects in query results.

What are my options? Is there perhaps some way I can encode the time in multiple rtree dimensions, to increase the available precision? Offsetting timestamps to a fixed recent date mitigates but doesn't eliminate the issue, since the range of the data is also large (dozens of years).